# The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building Consumer<ThemeProvider>(dirty)

Tags: flutter, dart

**Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this Consumer Widget**

EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK

```
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "0" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
Which: means none were found but one was expected

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

#4 main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/flutter/MyProject/dumpit/test/widget_test.dart:19:5)

(elided one frame from package:stack_trace)

This was caught by the test expectation on the following line:

file:///C:/flutter/MyProject/dumpit/test/widget_test.dart line 19
The test description was:
Counter increments smoke test
```

Comment: are you trying to run the default test on your app? When do you get this error?

Comment: when I run the command 'flutter test' at that time its shows the exception.

Comment: ok, but this is the default test you get when you make a new project, yet by the looks of it, your app is not the default app, so of course you get an error. What do you expect to happen? What are you trying to achieve by running the default test against your app?

Answer (score 0):

There was default test case file present in test folder which was against my app model and hence threw an error. I got rid of it to solve my test run